# Why does Function have both implicit and explicit prototype references, and can I set the implicit reference?

Tags: javascript, function, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

After reading this documentation:
http://es5.github.io/#x4.2.1

I was confused by the two prototype references on CF, and by this statement:

> The property named CFP1 in CFp is shared by cf1, cf2, cf3, cf4, and
>   cf5 (but not by CF)

Much of the literature on Javascript points out that functions are first class objects, and as such I'd expect to be able to set their implicit prototype reference like an object to achieve prototypal inheritance (disclaimer: I don't actually know what I'd use this inheritance for, but it occurred to me to see if it's possible).  Can I set this implicit prototype on a function, or will it always point to Function.prototype (I'm assuming that's the default).  And why does Function have both explicit and implicit prototypes?  Also do any other types in Javascript have both explicit and implicit prototype references or is Function unique in this regard?

Comment: Okay, I completely rewrote my answer trying to focus on what I believe you're missing. It was hard to decide what to leave out, but detailing everything would require too much space and time. I hope the new answer helps!

Comment: @bfavaretto Thank you!! Reading it now and will leave any feedback on your answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider the diagram from the specification, and the code below it, which tries to reproduce what's going on:

[image]

```
function CF() {};            // the constructor
CF.P1 = 'foo';               // P1 is an own property of the constructor; P2 is the same
var CFp = { CRP1: 'bar' };   // for now, just an object, with a CRP1 property
CF.prototype = CFp           // set CFp as the 'explicit prototype property' of CF;
                             // only constructors have such a property
var cf1 = new CF();          // an instance; 
var cf2 = new CF();          // another instance; cf3..cf5 are constructed the same way
Object.getPrototypeOf(cf1);  // CFp; this is the 'implicit prototype link' from cf1 to CFp;
                             // put another way, CFp became the [[Prototype]] of cf1
```

You said you were confused by this sentence: *the property named CFP1 in CFp is shared by cf1, cf2, cf3, cf4, and cf5 (but not by CF)*. Consider this:

```
cf1.CRP1;   // 'bar' - found on CFp through cf1
cf2.CRP1;   // 'bar' - found on CFp through cf2
CF.CRP1;    // undefined
```

So what that sentence means that you can access the contents of `CRP1` from `cf1..cf5`, but not from the constructor `CF` (remember, functions/constructors are objects too, thus they can have properties). And that's because `CFp` (the "owner" of `CRP1`) is not the `[[Prototype]]` of `CF`, it's just the value pointed by the `CF.prototype` property. The `prototype` property only exist in function objects, and is used solely to define the `[[Prototype]]` of instances created by invocations of the function is invoked as a constructor (like in `new CF()`). The fact that both `[[Prototype]]` and `prototype` read as "prototype" is the source of great confusion – and maybe part of what is confusing you; hopefully, it's less confusing now. With that in mind, I'll try to shortly answer your other questions.

> Much of the literature on Javascript points out that functions are first class objects, and as such I'd expect to be able to set their implicit prototype reference like an object to achieve prototypal inheritance [...].

In ES5 there is no way to directly *set* the implicit prototype reference (or `[[Prototype]]`) of an existing object, except for the non-standard `__proto__` property. What you can do is create *new* objects with a given `[[Prototype]]`. You can do that with `var obj = new ConstructorFunction()`, where the `[[Prototype]]` of `obj` is `ConstructorFunction.prototype`, or with `var obj = Object.create(someOtherObj)`, where the `[[Prototype]]` of `obj` is `someOtherObj`. The later versions of the language introduced [`Object.setPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf) to do that, but its use is discouraged for performance reasons.

> Can I set this implicit prototype on a function, or will it always point to Function.prototype (I'm assuming that's the default).

Yes, with `__proto__` or `Object.setPrototypeOf`. But usually you shouldn't.

> And why does Function have both explicit and implicit prototypes? Also do any other types in Javascript have both explicit and implicit prototype references or is Function unique in this regard?

`Function` ("the `Function` constructor") is just a function, and as any other function it has a `prototype` property; it's also an object, and as (almost) any other object is has a `[[Prototype]]` object. There are standard constructors for other types too, like `Object`, `String`, `Array`, `Boolean`, `Number`. They're all functions, and have both a `prototype` and a `[[Prototype]]`.

Comment: A couple more to follow, but my first question is with regards to: "// set CFp as the 'explicit prototype property' of CF; only constructors have such a property."  My understanding is that JS doesn't have an explicit way to differentiate between constructor and standard functions, which is why constructor functions are capitalized by convention. Would it be true to say that all functions have an explicit prototype property, but it generally goes unused on non-constructor functions?

Comment: Yes, exactly! All functions are (potential) constructors, and they all have a .prototype property.

Comment: Ok, final bit - is it true that the function type's implicit [[Prototype]] defaults to Function.prototype, and that modifying Function.prototype will affect all functions? If that's so then I would think that functions can in fact be extended through prototypal inheritance, however all function instances must be extended in the same fashion (eg, there's no such thing as "prototypal instances of functions"). Apologize if I'm butchering the terminology!

Comment: Meant to say "prototypal classes of functions" above.

Comment: @JamesCadd Yes, modifying `Function.prototype` does add new methods to all function objects (one example would be a [shim to `Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Compatibility)). What you can't do is overwrite/replace `Function.prototype`. So every function you create (using a function declaration, a function expression or `new Function()`) will inherit from the default Function.prototype. Not sure what you mean by  "prototypal classes of functions", though.

Comment: That's exactly what I was wondering, thank you for the thorough explanation.

Comment: Thanks @Brian, I updated the answer to include a note on that.

Comment: @bfavaretto, this is a great answer. Only a code sample of defining q1 and q2 on at least two objects (cf1 and cf2) is missing for a complete explanation of the diagram.

Answer (score 0):

The implicit reference is set by the platform whenever a new instance is created by calling a constructor function, or class with the new keyword, or passing an object with shared members to Object.create method, adding the input parameters to the object and returning it from a factory function. The `explicit prototype property`, as it's called in ECMA-262 spec, is set by specifying the function for the reference: .prototype.constructor. The prototype object defined on this function is what defines inherited properties and sets the prototype chain. Here is an example using a factory function (my preference):

function range(from, to) {

```
let r = Object.create(range.methods);

r.from = from;
r.to = to;

return r;
```

}

range.methods = {

```
includes(x) {
    return this.from <= x && x <= this.to;
},

*[Symbol.iterator]() {
    for (let x = Math.ceil(this.from); x <= this.to; x++) yield x;
},

toString() {
    return "(" + this.from + "..." + this.to + ")";
}
```

};

The prototype in the chain, which establishes inheritance, is held by the internal property: [[prototype]] which can be referenced with `__proto__` or `Object.getPrototypeOf` method. In Chrome console: `Object.getPrototypeOf(Array).__proto__` will produce the prototype of Array. Inspecting this object will expose "Object" as the value of the constructor property. Furthermore, it will show that its `__proto__` is null.

BTW, Figure 1: Object/Prototype Relationships [https://262.ecma-international.org/14.0/#sec-objects], is a little misleading. The prototype object on CFp, is buried within CF.prototype. You have to follow CF.prototype.constructor to the CFp function, then to its prototype property. Using the example for Array above, that would be Array.prototype.constructor. This is a reference to the Object constructor function.